# Microsoft SQL server 2005 query on string: < ' '

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a Microsoft SQL table `tbl` with following record:

```
clmn1 (smallint NOT NULL) = '2012'
clmn2 (char (10) NOT NULL) = '620100' 
clmn3 (char (1) NOT NULL) = ''
```

When I execute the query below:

```
select * 
from tbl with (rowlock)  
where clmn1 = 2012 and clmn2 = '620100' and clmn3 <= ' '
```

Then the row above is found, which is correct.

But when executing the following query:

```
select * 
from tbl with (rowlock)  
where clmn1 = 2012 and clmn2 = '620100' and clmn3 < ' '
```

Then it finds nothing which is not normal. Because clmn3 is empty (''). `'' < ' ' = true`.

This format for the 2 sql queries must be used because we are working with Xisam that translates his own sql query to the above sql query formats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CHAR(1)` turns `''` into `' '` ... so `' '` is *NOT* `< ' '`. If you want an empty string treated like an empty string, stop using `CHAR` and use `VARCHAR`.

```
DECLARE @c CHAR(1);
SET @c = '';
SELECT 'x' + @c + 'x';
```

Result:

```
x x -- not xx
```